# HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Tags: c#, wcf

I am working on WCF REST Service and i am facing the above mentioned problem. I am new to WCF REST Service. Please Help me out of this problem. My Code is shown below.

> IService1.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.ServiceModel.Web;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    namespace WCFAJ
    {

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    //[WebGet ( UriTemplate = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json) ]
    List<User> Get();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet ( UriTemplate = "GET/{id}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json )]
    User GetById(int id);


    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method="POST", UriTemplate = "POST", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void Post(User user);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method="PUT", UriTemplate = "PUT", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void Put( User user);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method="DELETE", UriTemplate = "DELETE/{id}", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void Delete(int id);
    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}


// Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
[DataContract]
public class UsersContext : DbContext 
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}


public class User
{
    public int userid { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Fname { get; set; }
    public string Lname { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "Phone Number should be 10 characters long")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

//public class User
//{
//    bool boolValue = true;
//    string stringValue = "Hello ";

//    [DataMember]
//    public bool BoolValue
//    {
//        get { return boolValue; }
//        set { boolValue = value; }
//    }

//    [DataMember]
//    public string StringValue
//    {
//        get { return stringValue; }
//        set { stringValue = value; }
//    }
//} 
    }
```

> Service1.svc.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.ServiceModel.Web;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Linq;

    namespace WCFAJ
    {

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    List<User> user;
    List<User> IService1.Get()
    {
        UsersContext db = new UsersContext();
        user = db.Users.ToList();
        return user;
    }

    User IService1.GetById(int id)
    {
        UsersContext db = new UsersContext();
        User get;
        get = db.Users.Where(i => i.userid == id).Single();
        return get;
    }

    void IService1.Post(User uSer)
    {
        UsersContext db = new UsersContext();
        db.Users.Add(uSer); 
    }

    void IService1.Put(User useR)
    {
        UsersContext db = new UsersContext();
        User user1 = db.Users.Where(i => i.userid == useR.userid).Single();
        user1.Username = useR.Username;
        user1.Fname = useR.Fname;
        user1.Lname = useR.Lname;
        user1.Email = useR.Email;
        user1.Address = useR.Address;
        user1.Phone = useR.Phone;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    void IService1.Delete(int id)
    {
        UsersContext db = new UsersContext();
        User x = db.Users.Where(i => i.userid == id).Single();
        db.Users.Remove(x);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    }
    }
```

> Web.Config

```
     <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=DEL1-DHP-28358;Initial Catalog=WCF;User ID=sa;Password=Global@123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
     <appSettings>
     <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
     </appSettings>
     <system.web>
     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
     </system.web>
     <system.serviceModel>
     <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
          <binding name="WebHttpBinding">
              <security mode="Transport">
                  <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"></transport>
              </security>
          </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
     </bindings>

     <services>
      <service name="WCFAJ.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WCFAJ.Service1Behavior" >
          <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" contract="WCFAJ.IService1">
              <identity>
                  <dns value="localhost"/>
              </identity>
          </endpoint>
          <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                  <add baseAddress="http://localhost:55610/Service1.svc/" />
              </baseAddresses>
          </host>
      </service>
       </services>

       <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
       <behavior name="WCFAJ.Service1Behavior">
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="false" />
         <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
       </behavior>
       </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
            <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors> 
        <protocolMapping>
          <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" >
         <serviceActivations>
          <add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory" relativeAddress="Service1.svc" service="WCFAJ.Service1"/>
        </serviceActivations>
        </serviceHostingEnvironment>
        </system.serviceModel>
        <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
  -->
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        </system.webServer>
         <entityFramework>
         <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
          <parameters>
           <parameter value="v11.0" />
           </parameters>
           </defaultConnectionFactory>

            <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
             </providers>
             </entityFramework>
             </configuration>
```

Comment: Did you check your configuration details for the service? is it working fine?

Comment: I have no idea where and what to change. I am totally new to this.

Comment: Did it work at least one time before not working?

Comment: No, It didn't work for a single time.

Answer (score 1):

Your endpoint isn't a REST endpoint. REST endpoints are defined with a specific binding (webHttpBinding) and behavior (webHttp). Add to `WCFAJ.Service1`, in addition to what you have, `endpoint` for REST, like:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="REST" contract="WCFAJ.IService1"/>
```

and to `<endpointBehaviors>`:

```
<behavior name="REST">
              <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
```

Comment: Now facing the problem "Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]"

Comment: Try to set security mode to None

Comment: Getting Error 404.3 When I am running it in IIS.

Comment: And Error "Operation 'GetById' in contract 'IService1' has a path variable named 'id' which does not have type 'string'.  Variables for UriTemplate path segments must have type 'string'." when simply running it.